# How do i get an automatic merge comment in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, tfvc

In source control systems and tools like tortoises for svn or sourcetree for git, when I am committing a merge, I can usually just left a default comment generated by the tool that is basically a summary of what changes were merged. In visual studio using TFS, there is a comment textbox right above the changes list, but I have to type it all manually. It's not super important but it is a time saver sometimes. Maybe i'm just not looking at the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extension [Auto Merge](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e18cc147-b4a2-4da7-8f90-9a0ffe464b07)

If you need set original comment setup [Settings](https://github.com/CDuke/AutoMerge/wiki/Settings) "comment_format" like {{OriginalComment}}

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TFS with Git, then this becomes less of an issue.  When you merge all the individual commits come along for the ride, so it's not necessary to re-describe them in the merge commit.

Comment: Unfortunately thats also not the case but i see what you are saying. Now, even in that scenario for some reason i like it better if i have the comment with all that big merge message.

Comment: If you care about having clean descriptive history - which you should - then a common practice in Git is to always do a rebase before you merge.  This way there won't be a separate merge commit.  You can also optionally do a squash as part of the rebase to eliminate extraneous commits and combine them as you see fit.

Comment: You forgot the part where I mentioned no, not using git for this project. On the other hand, I think that, when merging between environments a merge commit actually helps having a descriptive history.

Answer (score 1):

I have used TFS a lot, and unfortunately I don't think that option exists.  I usually copy my original checkin text and then paste it if I am doing multiple merges.  I realize this is a low tech way to do it and the original comment isn't generated for me.  If you want to be able to do this bad enough, you can probably write a Visual Studio plug in that would do it for you, or you could code up just about anything you want to add with the Team Foundation Server SDK.

Comment: Sadly i think you might be right or the option is ridiculously hidden somewhere.